# How to access Facebook from a Playframework service

Tags: facebook, playframework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Library to Integrate Facebook login with Play Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478532/library-to-integrate-facebook-login-with-play-framework)

I use playframework to make Json/Rest services - no webinterface.
I want to make a service, which posts a message on a Facebook wall. 
I had a look at fbconnect and fbgraph, but they seem to only support webinterface.
Am I right ?

Of course, I can just access the Facebook graph API directly, but I would like to know if there are better ways. Later I want to do a lot more with the graph api.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478532/library-to-integrate-facebook-login-with-play-framework][1]
?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478532/library-to-integrate-facebook-login-with-play-framework

Comment: Yes, facebook has a Java API which you can call from your backend (playframework).  The other option is to do the call's from the client side (i.e. your site visitors browser using javascript that interacts with facebook).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post to any user's wall you will need the OAuth dialog in order to FB grant access to your app on the user's wall, at least for the first time.

If you are posting to your system's wall then you can get the access token's for your application and store it somewhere.